# K3S Traefik only reachable via Wireguard VPN

Tags: traefik, k3s, wireguard

I have a vServer rented that i want to use as a tool server for my private projects. I have installed wireguard (Wireguard should be the only service reachable from the outsite) and set up ufw (Blocking everything except Wireguard). I have installed k3s with prebuild Traefik. My idea is that this Traefik is only reachable through  the Wireguard VPN.

What I've tried so far:

- UFW rules (Does not work because it collides with K3S automatic iptable configurations. Those rules are also very confusing to me...)
- Traefik entrypoint address: Traefik does not work with the IP from the wireguard interface
- Reconfigure service loadbalancer for traefik: When i reconfigure the loadbalancer service for Traefik (Currently listening on the public IP) the changes are not saved.

Does anybody has a hint what could be the solution? I am going nuts ...

Cheers